# Determine which Button was pressed in Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm making a simple little utility while learning Python.  It dynamically generates a list of buttons:

```
for method in methods:
    button = Button(self.methodFrame, text=method, command=self.populateMethod)
    button.pack({'fill': 'x', 'expand': 1, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 3})
```

That part works fine.  However, I need to know which of the buttons was pressed inside `self.populateMethod`.  Any advice on how I might be able to tell?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use lambda to pass arguments to a command:

```
def populateMethod(self, method):
    print "method:", method

for method in ["one","two","three"]:
    button = Button(self.methodFrame, text=method, 
        command=lambda m=method: self.populateMethod(m))
    button.pack({'fill': 'x', 'expand': 1, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 3})
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the command method is not passed any event object.

I can think of two workarounds:

- associate a unique callback to each button
- call `button.bind('<Button-1>', self.populateMethod)` instead of passing self.populateMethod as `command`. self.populateMethod must then accept a second argument which will be an event object.

  Assuming that this second argument is called `event`, `event.widget` is a reference to the button that was clicked.

Comment: I did the second method and it seems to do what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: If you use `bind` instead of taking advantage of the built-in `command` attribute you lose the ability to use Tkinter's built-in ability to navigate and click buttons with the keyboard. Of course, you can apply a bunch of bindings to handle all the special cases, but it's easier just to use the `command` attribute.

Comment: @BryanOakley: indeed; your suggestion of using lambdas is much cleaner.

Comment: Also, for anyone considering this 2nd method (binding to click instead of command), I would not recommend it for the "command" built-in is very "button-like" and will call the method only if the button is indeed clicked and activated. Binding it to a "Button-1" event may trigger undesired behavior, such as your button calling the method when you click on it even if said button is disabled.